# How to read the data from Excel sheet and print the result on console while working on protractor

Tags: protractor

I am working on AngularJs application testing framework where I am using Protractor. I want to read the data (urls, usernames, passwords) from an excel sheet. I am using the following code but it's showing me errors.

Please find the below code:

```
var Excel = require('exceljs');
var wrkbook = new Excel.Workbook();

wrkbook.xlsx.readFile('E:\\Login_Data.xlsx').then(function() 
{
    var worksheet = wrkbook.getWorksheet('Sheet1');
    worksheet.eachRow(function (Row, Test_URL) 
    {
        console.log("Row " + Test_URL + " = " + JSON.stringify(Row.User_Name));
    });
});
```

The data from excel sheet is :

```
Test_URL    User_Name   Password
http://...com   abc@1111    xyz@333
```

Please let me know your positive inputs so that I can run my code and proceed forward.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`eachRow` isn't getting the `Test_URL` variable that you set as function parameter; that is instead the row index.

For getting every value of the row, you can use `Row.values`, and also you could the value of each Cell (corresponding to that row) with `.getCell`.

So it should be something like this:

```
var Excel = require('exceljs');
var wrkbook = new Excel.Workbook();

wrkbook.xlsx.readFile('E:\\Login_Data.xlsx').then(function() 
{
    var worksheet = wrkbook.getWorksheet('Sheet1');
    worksheet.eachRow(function (Row, rowIndex) 
    {
        var test_url = Row.getCell(1).value;
        var user_name = Row.getCell(2).value;
        var password = Row.getCell(3).value;
        // do whatever you want with those variables.
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello eLRuLL,Thanks a lot for your help. I am trying to run this but I am getting no specs found. Please find the below msg: E:\Demo\Fetch the data from Json file>protractor conf1.js
(node:10520) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[12:17:25] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[12:17:25] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[12:17:28] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://10.212.134.202:61671/wd/hub
Started

No specs found
Finished in 0.006 seconds. Is any changes required?

Comment: I am also trying to run different js files and they are running absolutely fine.

Comment: I have also added var os = require('os'); 
os.tmpDir = os.tmpdir; in my code still I am getting the same warning.